# Bug in K&R second edition?

Tags: c, bounds

Here's something that looks like a bug to me, however I am confused that my observation does not seem to pop up anywhere else on the internet, given the age and popularity of the book. Or maybe I am just bad at searching or it is not a bug at all.

I am talking about the "print out the longest input line" program from chapter one. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 /* maximum input line length */

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print the longest input line */
main()
{
    int len; /* current line length */
    int max; /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE]; /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

 /* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Now, it seems to me that it should be `lim-2` as opposed to `lim-1` in the for condition of getline. Otherwise, when the input is exactly of maximum length, that is 999 characters followed by `'\n'`, getline will index into `s[MAXLINE]`, which is out of bounds, and also all kinds of horrible things might happen when copy is called and `from[]` does not end with a `'\0'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're confused somewhere.  This loop condition:

```
for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
```

Ensures that `i` is never greater than `lim - 2`, so in the maximum-length case, `i` is `lim-1` after the loop exits and the null character is stored into that last position.

Comment: Alright, thanks. HOWEVER, just to make easier examples, set MAXLINE to 3 as opposed to 1000. For the input a<ENTER> aa<ENTER> the program will print a as the longest line.

Comment: That's because both of those lines have the same length.  There's a `>`, not a `>=` in the test to overwrite `longest`.

Comment: Why should aa\n be treated to have the same length as a\n for MAXLINE == 3   ?

Comment: Because the loop *stops reading* when it fills the buffer.  Step through that loop in a debugger and you'll see why immediately.

Comment: Sorry for not expressing myself clearly. By now I understand why the program does what it does. My question was why it is not considered a bug that the program does not correctly recognize inputs of maximum length as the longest input line. After all, aa\n is obviously longer than a\n AND within maximum length - yet the program fails to recognize aa\n as longest input line in my example case.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of 999 non-\n characters followed by a \n, c never equals \n. When the for loop exits, c is equal to the last non-newline character.

So c != '\n' and doesn't enter the block that does i++ so i never goes out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, I did not account for the short circuit evaluation of the for condition.

Answer (score 1):

When the input is of length `999` and is followed by `\n`, value of limit is `1000` and the value of `lim -1` will become `999` and the loop test condition `i < lim -1` will become false when `i` becomes `998`. For `i < 999`, `c == \n` never be true and hence array `s` will indexed to `s[999]` and not `s[1000]`